# How do I substitute dynamic parameter values to T4MVC using razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, t4mvc

Consider following:

```
 $("#myform").attr({ action:  "@Url.Action(MVC.Thing.Delete().AddRouteValue("id", myJsModel.Id )) });
```

I'm trying to set the action method of the form to a strongly typed T4MVC route. How do I insert a dynamic value from javascript into the route value?

I've seen the use of @: but I don't know how to insert it back into razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that using T4MVC here versus regular MVC syntax makes much difference when it comes to this issue.

When thing you might try is to generate a replaceable token on the server and do the replacement client side. e.g. something like

```
MVC.Thing.Delete().AddRouteValue("id", "SOMETOKEN")
```

And then take the generated path on the client and replace "SOMETOKEN" with myJsModel.Id.

Comment: Ok gotcha, I just thought there might be some special way of doing this.  I might use String.format function to do this with {0}. Thanks.